# Error: Call to a member function setRecipients() on null in standard_form_install_configure_submit()

Tags: drupal, xampp

I encounter this error while installing drupal. I installed it through standard installation, I'm on XAMPP in

> windows 10 
>   PHP 7.1.15

Don't have a domain yet so used my gmail account in setting up that site email address :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to opcache, and you can fix it by fine-tuning your opcache settings (via php.ini)

More details are here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2780071